# what is the type of field in MYSQL that Can store Integer or Double Values I mean in the same column you can store integer || Doubles ?

Tags: mysql

what is the type of field in MYSQL that Can store Integer or Double Values 
I mean in the same column you can store integer || Doubles ? 
What is this type or how can I do It?

Any efforts will be appreciates.

Comment: What makes you think such a type exists?

Comment: I Doesn’t think that there is a type ... Just i ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is such data type in mysql. Probably you might want varchar instead, and cast to  the right data type in your server side code(php, java ...), but it might cause performance overhead. I'm not sure how come you have a such strange data type requirement. If the data has to be stored in this way, consider add an extra column for flagging data type.

Comment: thanks ... i Will make it double and caste any integer to double

Answer (score 1):

There is no native MySQL datatype that meets your requirements.

In general, a DECIMAL datatype fits the bill, although that is an exact decimal value, and not a float-type approximation. And since it has a fixed decimal point, the range of values that can be stored is several orders of magnitude smaller than the DOUBLE type.

One option is to use a `VARCHAR` column, and store a character representation of the value.

Another (unwieldy) option would be to use a `BIT(64)` column.

But it seems that with either of those approaches, you would need some type of indicator as to which type of value was stored. And there's several drawbacks to both of those approaches. One big drawback is that these would allow for "invalid" values to be stored.

An approach I would consider (if I had this requirement) would be to use two columns, one of them `INTEGER`, the other `DOUBLE`, and specify a precedence, and allow a NULL value in the INTEGER column to represent that the value was stored in the `DOUBLE` column.

Answer (score 0):

INT - A normal-sized integer that can be signed or unsigned. If signed, the allowable range is from -2147483648 to 2147483647. If unsigned, the allowable range is from 0 to 4294967295. You can specify a width of up to 11 digits.

DOUBLE(M,D) - A double precision floating-point number that cannot be unsigned. You can define the display length (M) and the number of decimals (D). This is not required and will default to 16,4, where 4 is the number of decimals. Decimal precision can go to 53 places for a DOUBLE. REAL is a synonym for DOUBLE.

Answer (score 0):

you can use double data type and in your language(php,ja) show that value as a integer.

Comment: thank you ... i will try to make it double and cast any value to double

Answer (score 0):

I think you maybe miss understand how computers store numbers: either a number is an integer or it is a floating point number.  There is different circuitry for each in a processors Arithmetic Logic Unit (ALU).  You cannot have a number that is both.